# Update 1 million of data at a time using a loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, sql-update

I need to update 1 million of data at a time using a loop. This is what I have.

```
SET Rowcount 1000000
While (1 = 1)
   Begin
   Begin Transaction

   Update as
   Set as.productInd = 0
   From Product as
   Where as.ProductInd IS NULL
If @@RowCount = 0
Begin

Commit Transaction
Break

End
Commit Transaction

End
Set Rowcount 0
```

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: @Larnu  I want to check if the code is correct.

Comment: You are in a far better position to check that than we are, @A . Plus, [so] isn't a website for code validation.

Comment: @Larnu will keep you updated. Thanks

Comment: You don't want a transaction, otherwise you lose the gain of not blocking and not growing your transaction log. And you should just use `UPDATE TOP (1000000)`

Comment: @charlieface will remove the Begin and Commit Transaction. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SET ROWCOUNT` is on a deprecation pathway for `UPDATE`
statements ([here's the KB article about it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)). So if you're running against a contemporary or older version of the engine, you could use:

```
SET ROWCOUNT 1000000

   UPDATE Product
   SET productInd = 0
   WHERE productInd IS NULL

SET ROWCOUNT 0
```

A couple of notes:

- You only have one statement, so it's already implicitly wrapped in a transaction.
- Don't use `as` as a table alias; it's a reserved word. (I'm sort of surprised the compiler let you, in fact!)
- Since `ROWCOUNT` for updates is on the way out, if you still want to accomplish what you're asking you would need a loop within a stored procedure.